# Mac OS Folder action to rename and process emails

Tags: automation, applescript, automator

I am trying to create a small office document management system that would do the following. I would drag an email as an .eml file from Outlook into a folder on the Desktop. Upon receiving the file, the Action would do the following:

1. Add today's date to the beginning of the existing filename.
2. Ask me for the client code.
3. Add the client code at the end of the existing filename.

I have started with Rename Finder Items: Add Date. The system does append the date to the filename, however, instead of doing it once, it inserts the date 20 or so times.

Then when I insert the Ask for Text and assign to a variable ("Client code"), which later added through the Rename Finder, nothing happens.

Oh, and I tried to include the code:

tell application "Client Code and Rename"

```
activate
```

end tell

But it just does not work. Please help me to put it together. Thanks.

MacBook Pro, Mac OS X (10.6.5), 2 GHz Intel Core Duo, 2 GB

Comment: Basically you must not change the file name within the hot folder, because it re-triggers the folder action and you will run into an infinite loop.

Comment: Either that, or make the action detect when a file has already been renamed, and exit without re-renaming it.

Comment: Thank you both. How would the action detect when a file has been renamed and exit? Sorry, I have no coding experience and using the Automator is about how much I can master.

Comment: Jimmy, if you've not much coding experience, I would follow @vadian's advice and not change a filename within the watched folder.  Try and use a separate folder, which can even a sub-folder within the watched folder.